# How passwords are encrypted in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, encryption, passwords

There is a template ASP.NET Identity project. It implements Registration, Authorization... etc.

The question is, I want to use this template database for a WPF application. But the problem is that in order to implement authorization in WPF, we need to know which password hashing method is used, but alas, I can't find this information.

Please tell me what to do in such a situation, maybe who knows this algorithm? How did you deal with this problem?

I have already tried many encryption methods suggested by people on the Internet. But I didn't achieve anything.

One of the many tried hashing methods and a click handler for entering the program:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        string hashedPassword = HashPassword(password.Password);
        MessageBox.Show(hashedPassword);
        using (ModelContainer db = new ModelContainer())
        {
            if (txtLogin.Text != null && hashedPassword != null)
            {
                foreach (AspNetUsers user in db.AspNetUsers)
                {
                    if (txtLogin.Text.Equals(user.UserName) && hashedPassword.Equals(user.PasswordHash))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Login is successful!");
                        MainWindow Sform = new MainWindow();
                        this.Hide();
                        Sform.Show();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show("The username or password is incorrect!");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Enter all fields");
        }
}

public static string HashPassword(string password)
{
        byte[] salt;
        byte[] buffer2;

        if (password == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
        }

        using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes bytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 0x10, 0x3e8))
        {
            salt = bytes.Salt;
            buffer2 = bytes.GetBytes(0x20);
        }

        byte[] dst = new byte[0x31];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, dst, 1, 0x10);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer2, 0, dst, 0x11, 0x20);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(dst);
}
```

Comment: Passwords aren't encrypted. They're hashed.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/002650f48d2ea5d8fe1e746e6ef319d95661f325/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs#L18

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Why don't you make that an answer

Comment: I have already tried using Password Hasher to select the necessary cache, I have achieved some success, the hash is really very similar to the one I need, but unfortunately it differs. Therefore, I want to understand the intricacies of the work.

Comment: @Charlieface Unfortunately I was on my phone when I provided that link, so I wasn't really in a position to provide an answer beyond the link.

Comment: @Daniil Can you update your question with what you've tried based on the ASP.NET Core `PasswordHasher` code?